# executeFetchRequest hangs and never returns

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7

executeFetchRequest method of core data sometimes hangs and does not return error message also..

this is my code....

```
NSArray *fetchResults = [deleteContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Comment: If you are using multiple contexts it is possible this one is waiting for another to finish before it can finish, however the other context could be in the middle of something and be waiting on this one to finish - hence deadlock. To see if this is happening use the debugger once it hangs - press pause and see what is happening in other threads at this point in time. Also, there isn't enough code here to judge the context of what is happening... what are `deleteContext` what is the `fetchRequest` etc...

Comment: Please add more info on your context.